# React/Redux obtaining response from API

Tags: reactjs, redux, response, api-design

I can't quite figure out how to obtain in my React front the same result I get from my api in Postman.

for context I send a json formatted call of this nature :

```
{
    "bagel": false,
    "pretzel": false,
    "curry": true,
    "wurst": "true",
}
```

and I recieve the same sort of thing :

```
{
    "bagelavailability": false,
    "pretzelavailability": false,
    "curryavailability": true,
    "wurstavailability": "true",
}
```

but no matter what I do I can't get to console.log the received API answer.

Here's my current actions.jsx :

```
function FirstCall(specs) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const payload = CallOne.post(specs);
        payload.then((response) => {
            console.log(response); // undefined !!
            if (!response.ok) { // this if is entered but I guess null.ok is false by definition.
                dispatch(Notifications.error({ title: 'Message', message: 'error!' }));
            }
        });
    };
}
```

this is my call one code :

```
/* ************************************* */
/* ********       IMPORTS       ******** */
/* ************************************* */
import Api from './Api';

const Resource = Api.all('order');
Resource.init = (data) => {
    if (data) {
        const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        return {
            all: Resource.all,
            data() { return dataObj; },
            save(...args) {
                if (this.data()[Resource.identifier()]) {
                    return Resource.put(this.data()[Resource.identifier()], this.data(), ...args);
                }
                return Resource.post(this.data(), ...args);
            },
            one: Resource.one,
            url: Resource.url,
        };
    }
    return undefined;
};
/* ************************************* */
/* ********       EXPORTS       ******** */
/* ************************************* */
export default Resource;
```

and here's "API" :

```
/* ************************************* */
/* ********       IMPORTS       ******** */
/* ************************************* */
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import restful, { fetchBackend } from 'restful.js';

/* ************************************* */
/* ********       EXPORTS       ******** */
/* ************************************* */
export default restful('http://localhost:8080', fetchBackend(fetch));
```

Comment: Please share your `CallOne` code.  Your `then` needs to go in there.

Comment: Also consider using `axios` to make things easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: I don't have the liberty of changing the stack :( -- added the CallOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so below are the files setup I have to hack through the issue :

The hack I found is to make a reducer for the first call even thought that shouldn't be necessary and via it's success handle grab the response check it out : (better solutions most welcome)

/Redux/EventTypes.jsx :

```
export default {
    FIRST_CALL: { type: 'FIRST_CALL' },
    FIRST_CALL_FULFILLED: { type: 'FIRST_CALL_FULFILLED' },
    SECOND_CALL: { type: 'SECOND_CALL' },
    SECOND_CALL_FULFILLED: { type: 'SECOND_CALL_FULFILLED' },
};
```

/Redux/Reducers/FirstCall.jsx :

```
import EventTypes from '../EventTypes';

const initialState = {
    Document: {},
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EventTypes.FIRST_CALL_FULFILLED.type:
            return { ...state, Document: action.payload.body() };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

/Redux/Reducers/SecondCall.jsx :

```
import EventTypes from '../EventTypes';
import actions from '../../Components/CardCollection/actions';

const initialState = {
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EventTypes.SECOND_CALL_FULFILLED.type:
            const test = action.payload.body();
            const val = test.map(data => data.data());
            actions.generateDocument(val);
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

/Redux/Reducers/Reducers.jsx :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import FirstCall from './FirstCall';
import SecondCall from './SecondCall';


const reducers = combineReducers({
    firstCall: FirstCall,
    secondCall: SecondCall,
});


export default reducers;
```

/Common/Resources/FirstCall.jsx :

```
import Api from './Api';

const Resource = Api.all('firstcall');
Resource.init = (data) => {
    if (data) {
        const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        return {
            all: Resource.all,
            data() { return dataObj; },
            save(...args) {
                if (this.data()[Resource.identifier()]) {
                    return Resource.put(this.data()[Resource.identifier()], this.data(), ...args);
                }
                return Resource.post(this.data(), ...args);
            },
            one: Resource.one,
            url: Resource.url,
        };
    }
    return undefined;
};

export default Resource;
```

/Common/Resources/SecondCall.jsx :

```
import Api from './Api';

const Resource = Api.all('secondcall');
Resource.init = (data) => {
    if (data) {
        const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        return {
            all: Resource.all,
            data() { return dataObj; },
            save(...args) {
                if (this.data()[Resource.identifier()]) {
                    return Resource.put(this.data()[Resource.identifier()], this.data(), ...args);
                }
                return Resource.post(this.data(), ...args);
            },
            one: Resource.one,
            url: Resource.url,
        };
    }
    return undefined;
};

export default Resource;
```

/Components/CardCollection/SearchByType.jsx :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import actions from './actions';
import SearchByTypeComponent from './SearchByTypeComponent';

const SearchByType = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(SearchByTypeComponent);

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        firstCall: payload => dispatch(actions.firstCall(payload)),
    };
}

export default SearchByType;
```

/Components/CardCollection/SearchByTypeComponent.jsx :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const propTypes = {
    ExecuteAPIcall: React.PropTypes.func,
};

class SearchByTypeComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.generate = this.generate.bind(this);
    }

    generate() {
        const { ExecuteAPIcall} = this.props;
        const payload = {
            var1: false,
            var2: true,
            var3: false,
            var4: 'zert',
            var5: '',
            var6: '',
            var7: '',
            var8: '',
            var9: '',
        };
        ExecuteAPIcall(payload);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <button onClick={this.generate}>Générer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SearchByTypeComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default SearchByTypeComponent;
```

/Components/CardCollection/actions.jsx :

```
import types from '../../Redux/EventTypes';
import FirstCall from '../../Common/Resources/FirstCall';
import SecondCall from '../../Common/Resources/SecondCall';

function ExecuteAPIcall(specs) {
    const payload = FirstCall.post(specs);
    return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.FIRST_CALL, payload });

}

function ExecuteAPIcallPartTWO(response) {

    const payloadToPost = {
        var1: 'ohoy',
        var2: 'aaha',
        var3: 'ouhou',
        var4: response,
    };
    const payload2 = SecondCall.post(payloadToPost);
    payload2.then(
        () => dispatch =>
            dispatch(
console.log('success!');
}

const actions = {
    ExecuteAPIcall,
    ExecuteAPIcallPartTWO,
};

export {actions as default};
```